# In a Rails v4 has_many association how can you have a computed primary key column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails model that has an hstore (using the hstore_accessor gem). So when I set the primary key on a `has_many` association to an hstore field the generated SQL is just searching for `NULL` (Postgres).

So is there a way to define a custom method to compute the primary key of the association?

If I do:

```
has_many :email_blocks, lambda { |cm| where(email_address: cm.email_address) },
  foreign_key: :email_address
```

Then I can get most of the way there with this SQL:

```
SELECT "email_blocks".* FROM "email_blocks"
WHERE "email_blocks"."email_address" = '950b5f7b-9388-45f4-9c42-42e18337b09c'
AND "email_blocks"."email_address" = 'me@example.com'
```

But the first clause that is checking the primary key of the relation is unnecessary since this SQL will return what I want:

```
SELECT "email_blocks".* FROM "email_blocks"
WHERE "email_blocks"."email_address" = 'me@example.com'
```

Comment: The best answer is probably - YOU DON'T. ActiveRecord is built around using simple auto-indexing ids or UUIDs as primary keys and foreign keys. Using compound or computed PKs with ActiveRecord is  just going to bring boatloads of pain and suffering for very limited gains.

Comment: That's a silly answer. ActiveRecord is just a tool like any other and it has built in support for many cases like these. For example, you can set `primary_key` and `foreign_key` explicitly. The only reason that doesn't work here is because of the use of an hstore column. If the built-in options don't work, it's easy enough to write your own relation/association.